# Window numbering system?

Tags: windows

I have a garrison colonial house with vinyl tilt-in windows that need cleaning. I'm thinking to take the sashes outside in groups and hose them down, so I need to mark the sashes and frames with some sort of identifiers so I don't mix them up.

Problem: I can come up with a half dozen systems for identifying the windows, but I'm sure a couple of years down the road I'll have forgotten which system I used, confusing the heck out of yours truly.

Is there a standard way to identify a house's windows? Absent that, is there a system that, when you see the identifiers, you can figure out what it means?

Comment: Past experince has taught me that in new house builds it tends to go like:Frames turn up all sorts of sizes, some of them even fit the holes in the building but none of them are marked, glass turns up from a separate company with paper stickers saying the size on, the fitters spend ages looking through the glass for the ones they want for the frame theyve struggled to fit because it was the wrong size, they moan a lot about inability to measure and finish the day having fitted some of the glass, take some frames away because theyre plain wrong, toss the glass and return with frames that fit :)

Comment: ..and you wait 3 weeks for replacement glass

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Doesn't matter **what** system you use if you mark the sashes **and the frames** the same way and your system provides unique numbers/letters/nicknames/Braille encodings for each window.

1,2,3,4,5...

a,b,c,d,e...

000,001,010,011,100...

John, Paul, George, Ringo...

Eenie, Meenie, Miney, Moe....

I,II,III,IV,V...

Comment: Thanks. I figured that; I just wondered if there was some sort of Industry Standard Window Identification System that I could use...

Comment: My 1920s house in Toronto has the basement windows and sashes coded with Roman numerals on the edge.  I'm guessing that they were used because the original carpenter could apply the numbers with a few blow from a straight chisel.  Not likely to need a "C" for most houses

Comment: Wrecker/junk/scrap yards near me use some sort of paint or crayon pen to mark their car parts when they dismantle. It resists hosing off but can be cleaned off with a scrubber, and marks well on glass. A sharpie would probably also do well (on the glass). I'd mark the frame with something like a Post-it or paper stuck on with sticky tack)

Answer (score 5):

If you had a floor plan print for your house you could consider making a copy of that and label all the widows on it. Staple this up to the wall inside a garage or other similar place. Each window on the plans would be marked uniquely in a sequence. You would have to mark each of the removable units as you take them out which could be done with a Sharpie permanent marker or stick on label.

This system would avoid the need to mark the window frames as well but it would still make sense to mark the frames in similar manner in an inconspicuous place anyway.